# Doxygen documentation after members and XML commands

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense, doxygen, xml-comments

I am trying to get the best out of doxygen and IntelliSense, and found the [XML commands](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/xmlcmds.html) to be a pretty good win here: documentation get generated on one hand, while it appears during completion on the other hand.

One of the catches though, is the inline documentation after members.

The [doxygen manual](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html) mentions only one way to have documentation after members: `///<`. Unfortunately it clashes with Visual Studio's, as illustrated here:

```
enum
{
    A, ///< Doxygen understands this, but IntelliSense is oblivious to it.
    B, ///  <summary>IntelliSense understands this, but Doxygen applies it to the wrong member.</summary>
    C, ///< <summary>Doxygen understand this, but IntelliSense considers it to be invalid XML.</summary>
};
```

Is there a way to write documentation after members in XML in a way that is understood correctly by both Doxygen and Visual Studio, or should I fall back on commenting on the preceding line?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly pretty, but you can use `//!<` instead. That way Visual Studio won't try to parse the comment as XML.

As mentioned in the linked [doxygen documentation](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html):

> Most often one only wants to put a brief description after a member. This is done as follows:
>
> `int var; //!< Brief description after the member`
>
> or
>
> `int var; ///< Brief description after the member`